# Building an Arch Linux based live CD/USB

Tags: arch-linux, live-usb, livecd, distribution-media

After bootstrapping my Arch live CD, I try to install the `archiso` package with:

```
pacman -Sy archiso
```

but I get:

```
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/archiso_shutdown exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/archiso exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/archiso_loop_mnt exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/archiso_pxe_common exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/archiso_pxe_http exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/archiso_pxe_nbd exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/archiso_pxe_nfs exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/archiso_shutdown exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/install/archiso exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/install/archiso_kms exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/install/archiso_loop_mnt exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/install/archiso_pxe_common exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/install/archiso_pxe_http exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/install/archiso_pxe_nbd exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/install/archiso_pxe_nfs exists in filesystem
archiso: /usr/lib/initcpio/install/archiso_shutdown exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

I read [pacman wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman#Q%3a_I_get_an_error_when_updating%3a_.22file_exists_in_filesystem.22.21). So I tried:

```
pacman -Qo  /usr/lib/initcpio/archiso_shutdown
```

and I get:

```
error: No package owns /usr/lib/initcpio/archiso_shutdown
```

As for:

> If you had installed a program manually without using pacman or a frontend, you have to remove it and all its files and reinstall properly using pacman.

After bootstrapping the live CD, `pacman` is the first program run.

Answer (score 2):

Never synch the database without updating your packages. **Always** use `pacman -Syu`, otherwise you may experience the sort of breakage you are seeing.

Essentially, you have told pacman to refresh it's local database listing for a specific package, and not updated any of the other packages (that may share libraries) at the same time. This is why [partial upgrades are unsupported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported).

You can read the [parable of the sad user](http://gist.io/5660494) that fell into this trap for a more concrete example.